# No etherbase set and no accounts found as default

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, nodes

I am getting: "No etherbase set and no accounts found as default"

when trying to sync my node using:

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Then my node starts but seem to be a local instance not connected to the testnet:

```
WARN [09-29|09:28:24] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/windows-amd64/go1.9
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\\Users\\jc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\testnet\\geth\\chaindata cache=1024 handles=1024
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Writing custom genesis block
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\\Users\\jc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\testnet\\geth\\ethash count=3
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\\Users\\jc\\AppData\\Ethash                                   count=2
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca3a2d td=1048576
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=419410…ca3a2d td=1048576
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca3a2d td=1048576
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [09-29|09:28:24] Starting P2P networking
INFO [09-29|09:28:26] UDP listener up                          self=enode://e256e2a241f56a0f65d873894f162711893714e5d21e83994c7f742542023cd5ce2cfc4216434b02534c49ab31c57f7278c4f0100951a0d6645504ef455940d7@[::]:30303
INFO [09-29|09:28:26] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://e256e2a241f56a0f65d873894f162711893714e5d21e83994c7f742542023cd5ce2cfc4216434b02534c49ab31c57f7278c4f0100951a0d6645504ef455940d7@[::]:30303
INFO [09-29|09:28:26] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [09-29|09:28:26] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Any idea how to solve this error message?

Thanks! Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No etherbase set and no accounts found as default" doesn't look like an error, it is warning based on the log. In order to fix it you need it create account `geth --datadir=/wherever account new`, but most probably it will not fix problem with synchronization. It looks like the client can't find peers for some reason, in can be connection problem or firewall.